# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/BenchmarkThroughput

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I try to run TestDFSIO on CDH4.4, which I started through command line (and not Cloudera Manager). 
This is the command I run:

```
bin/hadoop jar hadoop-test-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar TestDFSIO -Ddfs.replication=1 -write -nrFiles 2 -fileSize 4000
```

And this is the error I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/BenchmarkThroughput
        at org.apache.hadoop.test.AllTestDriver.main(AllTestDriver.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BenchmarkThroughput
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 6 more
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This class is part of the HDFS test code, not the main HDFS library. You will not find it available automatically on the classpath in a cluster.

The test code is published as compiled artifacts with Hadoop, but just different artifacts. CDH is no different. For CDH 4.4, you can find the HDFS test classes in artifact `hadoop-hdfs-2.0.0-cdh4.4.0-tests.jar`
which you can depend on in your Maven build for example.

https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/2.0.0-cdh4.4.0/